# Automatic monitor and sound switch through HDMI

Tags: sound, hdmi, monitor

I am new to Linux. I have installed Ubuntu MATE 18.04 to a Lenovo g505 laptop, and I was wondering if there is a way to save monitor and sound options when HDMI is connected to TV, and when it is disconnected to switch automatically back to the laptop's hardware, just like in Windows.

There is a problem too. Everytime I connect HDMI, the TV's speakers are not recognised and I will have to run the command:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

When I run this they are recognised, but this has to happen every time. And when I disconnect HDMI and manually switch to laptop's speakers, the volume is frozen in one level and cannot be adjusted, until I reboot the PC. Any ideas?